# Can't use cx_Oracle on MacOS even though it is already installed

Tags: python, pycharm, cx-oracle

I opened a Terminal window under MacOS High Sierra and when I run the python command "import cx_Oracle" everything is fine.

When I run a .py file on a PyCharm project, which the very first line of code is "import cx_Oracle" I get the following error message:

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'".

I have aliased my python3 command to python and when I run the command "python -m pip install cx_Oracle" I get a message telling me it's alright:

"Requirement already up-to-date: cx_Oracle in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (8.0.0)"

I simply don't know what to do. Is that a matter of adding any path to any environment variable or a virtual environment under PyCharm related problem?

Why does my Python Interpreter running through Terminal not alert me about any error, when I run the install command, everything is fine, but through my Python IDE I keep being alerted about a non existent module?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is PyCharm actually running python3? Aliasing in the shell is unlikely to affect PyCharm

Comment: It is set to use the 3.8 Interpreter. I think this has something to do with the virtual environment and the pip version  I tried to add the cx_Oracle package to the original project (since that under Project preferences, I noticed it isn't among the installed packages) and PyCharm brings an error: "Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/Users/username/PycharmProjects/dbPreProcessing/venv/bin/python'." It's kinda confusing pip/python different versions and its conflicts...

Answer (score 0):

Try installing cx_Oracle using the python binary that PyCharm runs.  I.e. with something like:

```
/Users/cjones/j/PycharmProjects/p1/venv/bin/python -m pip install cx_Oracle
```

The python binary is shown in the PyCharm Run console when you execute a script.